# Limitations for reviewing Documentation topics

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

There are a lot of samples of low quality reviewing. For example at Documentation section.

Some kind of advertising was added in this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/107325):

[image]

Maybe it is better to set limitations for reviewers.

For example the limit by *tag* score can be applied.

Comment: The same user also tried to edit that link into a highly upvoted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14154544).

Comment: We need a  "Brad signal". It's like the bat signal, but instead of Batman, it calls Brad Larson :-D  He's probably the most active moderator where it comes to handing out review suspensions.

Comment: We could (involuntarily) drag him into a chatroom.

Comment: Here's another example of 3 low-quality reviewers. How could you approve [that](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/133698)? Fortunately, it wasn't approved because of 4 other good reviewers. We really need some limits on documentation review.

Answer (score 23):

IMHO the 100 rep to review docs contributions is way too low.  You have users reviewing who have never reviewed anything before.  These are users who are still trying to figure SO out and I do not think they should be making review decisions yet.

If we do not trust users until 500 rep for the late answers and new post review queues then we should at least wait for that level of trust with Docs.  Personally I would prefer 2K rep like we do for suggested edits but if that is too high then it should be at least 500 rep like the first set of review queues user get introduced to.  We could also tie it into the 1K Privilege, Established User, as an extra.

Comment: Agreed. Only two of the Approvers are below 500 rep though, and one barely so. I'd prefer some other threshold as well - maybe the Deputy badge.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is easy to earn 2k rep asking a populist questions like "Is Good better than Evil?" (at least in *Java* tag). Sorry :)

Comment: @AlexK Agreed.  But if we are to use rep to dole out privs then we need to come up with some number and I do not think more than 2K would fly.

Comment: @NathanOliver A tons of doubtful approves are coming from 500+ (but less than 2k) rep users

Comment: @AlexK there's also a ton coming from sub 500 rep. which of those groups could we easily cut out? Personally i'd rather see the documentation review queue go away and go back to it being handled from the dashboards.

Comment: That or only have requests older than 48 hours show in the queue.

Comment: Sonetimes, it can be tough to decide whether or not to accept a change, especially if you are skimming. Not saying you should, but it happens. I also think a guide to reviewing might be a good idea.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think getting rid of the queue completely is a good idea. At the moment the queue was introduced, there were around two thousand pending edits, and now there are rarely 10 edits pending at the same time across all tags. That means the queue works in terms of making moderation easier.

Comment: There's also currently no incentive in the form of badges to review documentation. I assume this is because Documentation is still in beta, and expect that there will be added some to match the other review queues. This problem will only become more pressing, making a higher rep-threshold vital.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that would help would be having a guide introducing people to reviewing/giving them an overview. In addition, I think it makes sense to set a threshold on the tag score so people who are accepting/rejecting changes have some knowledge about the subject that is being changed. Unlike Nathan, I disagree that the reputation requirement should be upped so high: the Documentation project is sort of like a wiki where everyone can contribute and most can help moderate. Maybe a small raise on the minimum reputation required might be a good idea, but 500 is in my opinion unnecessarily high.